# Redirecting url in htaccess file

Tags: php

Please Help

The dynamic url generated will be

> /project-management/pmp-certification-classroom-training.php?loc=xyz&id=12345

I need to redirect the url in htaccess file and it has to generate the the url like

> /project-management/pmp-certification-classroom-training-xyz/12345

Comment: Do you mean that if someone goes to your first URL it should redirect to the second?

Comment: yes, i want to write RewriteRule in htacess file please help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule  ^project-management/pmp-certification-classroom-training/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)$ pmp-certification-classroom-training.php?loc=$1&project_id=$2 [L, QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `loc` need to be appended!

Comment: You need to give the file path from document root before the filename. Let me if you still get 500 error.

Comment: Thanks for the help i tried adding file page like                 RewriteRule  ^$ ([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(.*)/(.*)$ project-management/pmp-certification-classroom-training.php?loc=$1&project_id=$2 [L, QSA] but still coming 500 error